# Flattening with ValueInjecter

Tags: c#, valueinjecter

I try to map multiple objects to a view model object with [ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/). But it does not work as I expect it.

**Code:**

```
class Call
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }
}

class Operation
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CallNumber { get; set; }
    public string TimeFrom { get; set; }
}

class Customer
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class CallViewModel
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string OperationTimeFrom { get; set; }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var call = new Call { Number = "001337", CustomerNumber = "000001" };
        var op = new Operation { ID = 1, CallNumber = "001337", TimeFrom = "08:00" };
        var customer = new Customer { Number = "000001", Name = "John Doe" };

        var viewModel = new CallViewModel();
        viewModel.InjectFrom(call, op, customer);

        Console.WriteLine("Number:\t\t\t" + viewModel.Number);
        Console.WriteLine("CustomerName:\t\t" + viewModel.CustomerName);
        Console.WriteLine("OperationTimeFrom:\t" + viewModel.OperationTimeFrom);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Number:            001337
CustomerName:      John Doe
OperationTimeFrom: 08:00
```

**Effective Output:**

```
Number:            00001
CustomerName:      
OperationTimeFrom:
```

**Notice**

The `Call.Number`, represented as `Number` in `CallViewModel` gets overwritten by `Customer.Number`. Both `CustomerName` and `OperationTimeFrom` never get the value of its designated source `Customer.Name` and `Operation.TimeFrom`.

What do I have to do in that scenario? Does ValueInjecter even support this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you thought of flattening in a different way, 
the way it works is that you go from

```
obj.Prop.Prop1.Prop2 to obj.PropProp1Prop2
```

this is your code modified:

```
using System;
using Omu.ValueInjecter;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var call = new Call { Number = "001337", CustomerNumber = "000001" };
            var op = new Operation { ID = 1, CallNumber = "001337", TimeFrom = "08:00" };
            var customer = new Customer { Number = "000001", Name = "John Doe" };

            var model = new
                            {
                                Call = call,
                                Customer = customer,
                                Operation = op
                            };

            var viewModel = new CallViewModel();
            viewModel.InjectFrom<FlatLoopValueInjection>(model);

            Console.WriteLine("Number:\t\t\t" + viewModel.CallNumber);
            Console.WriteLine("CustomerName:\t\t" + viewModel.CustomerName);
            Console.WriteLine("OperationTimeFrom:\t" + viewModel.OperationTimeFrom);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        class Call
        {
            public string Number { get; set; }
            public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }
        }

        class Operation
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string CallNumber { get; set; }
            public string TimeFrom { get; set; }
        }

        class Customer
        {
            public string Number { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        class CallViewModel
        {
            public string CallNumber { get; set; }
            public string CustomerName { get; set; }
            public string OperationTimeFrom { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that before posting my question. I used `viewModel.InjectFrom<FlatLoopValueInjection>(call, op, customer);` but ended with the same output as above

Comment: OK I understand now that the `FlatLoopValueInjection` looks for the property name to match. Is there an Injection that matches the type name? If not, is it possible to create one?

Comment: @Sandro you could, just look in the source code of FlatLoopValueInjection